# Does OpenAI Gym or Tensorforce require a normalized action space?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, python-3.x, openai-gym, implementation

I am learning to use OpenAI Gym to make a custom environment with continuous action and observation spaces and apply reinforcement learning algorithms using the Tensorforce library. The problem is that the action space must be normalized (values in the [-1, 1] interval) in order to work; otherwise, when using the required (not normalized) values, it gives an error.

These are the lines I'm using:

```
self.action_space = spaces.Box(np.array([4.6, 80.0]), np.array([4.8, 180.0]), dtype=np.float32) # Gives error 
self.action_space = spaces.Box(np.array([-1, -1]), np.array([1, 1]), dtype=np.float32) # OK, but not desired
```

The error I get when using the required (not normalized) values:

```
File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorforce\environments\openai_gym.py", line 378, in unflatten_action
    if np.isinf(action).any() or np.isnan(action).any():

TypeError: ufunc 'isinf' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

where `action` is `{'2'}`.

Is there something I'm missing here? Or does OpenAI Gym or Tensorforce work only with normalized action values? If so, why? And how can this be avoided?